# Can you use FTP with Google Compute?

Tags: ftp, google-compute-engine

Hey I'm just wondering if there is a way to setup a regular FTP server on Google Compute.  SFTP works, but I'm migrating from a physical server to google, and already have 100's of regular FTP users.  I would rather not have to get them all to switch to SFTP if I don't have to.  (I would like to do that long-term, but I don't want to break all of their connections when I migrate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use FTP. You must

1. Install an FTP server
2. Open port 21 & a range of higher ports, eg 49152-65534.
3. Configure the FTP server to use the port range from (2) for Passive FTP
4. Configure the FTP server for your users/destinations.

That said FTP is a *very* insecure protocol. Migrating to SFTP is very important for your users' security.