# FTP on Windows 2008 r2 on Google Compute Engine

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2008-r2, google-compute-engine

I'm having difficulty setting up FTP to my new Windows 2008 R2 Server on the Google Compute Engine.  I've tried to follow the basic steps here: [Can you use FTP with Google Compute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634667/can-you-use-ftp-with-google-compute)

I need deeper help with more of a step by step approach with details as to where to enter IP ranges, IP addresses, etc.

I've setup many FTP servers on Windows before, but with this one FileZilla gives me the error of "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".  I've even tried to setup Anonymous FTP to no avail.  It seems that it is not even reaching the server, so I'm fairly certain it's a firewall issue.

I've tried to open a passive range of tcp:5000-6000 on both the Google Network's firewall rules and my Windows Firewall on the server.  Port 21 is open in both.

Incidentally, WebDav is working well, although that's probably because http and https are opened when setting up the server.  Also, I know FTP is insecure. I have no choice in that matter.

Really baffling. Thank you.

Comment: Hrm. I've solved a lot of OS issues by searching here.  Google Compute Bronze support links me here.  I'm a programmer but often need to wrestle with server issues as part of that job.

Comment: @T.D.M. can you connect to the FTP server from the Windows machine itself, i.e., as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, to isolate the firewall as the issue and not the FTP server itself?

Answer (score 0):

**List firewall rules on all instances**

gcloud compute firewall-rules list
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows

**Add allowed ips to RDP firewall rule**

gcloud compute firewall-rules create rdp --allow tcp:3389 --source-ranges CIDR_ADDRESSES

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows